# Restricting the generic types returned by an interface subclass

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Say I have 2 subclasses of an interface such that

```
public interface ITradable {
    T GetTradeManager<T>(ManagerLocation location) where T: ITradeManager
}

public interface ISpendable : ITradable {}
public interface ILoanable : ITradable {}
```

`ITradeManager` has two sub-interfaces of its own: `ISpendManager` and `ILoanManager`.

Now, when dynamically dealing with object that implements `ITradable`, I need to retrieve the appropriate manager depending on which derived class is being used.  The potential issue with my design appears to be that I could potentially try and retrieve `ILoanManager` from an `ISpendable` implementation.  eg:

```
ISpendable spendable = //get
ILoanManager manager = spendable.GetTradeManager<LoanManager>(location)
```

Now, this particular tradable may use a `TradeManager` that isn't `LoanManager`.  However, it might also be the case that a tradable can be both loaned OR spent, so I need to be able to specify in many cases.

Am I wrong to think this is bad design?  Is there a better way of doing this?  I basically want ITradable to be as generic as possible, but also enforce that ISpendables only return ISpendManagers and ILoanables only return ILoanManagers.

Comment: I'd do a cosmetic change to make the semantics clearer: rename the method to `GetTradeManagerOfType<T>` and the implementation should simply return the required manager if available or `null` if the specified `T` doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is you need to have some common naming convention for both service and manager.

In your base service `GetTrademanager` method whenever a Manager is requested make sure it matches the starting name of the current Service.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    namespace ConsoleApplication6
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var child1Service = new Child1Service();
                var child2Service = new Child2Service();
                var child1Manager = child1Service.GetTradeManager<IChild1Manager>();
                var child2Manager = child2Service.GetTradeManager<IChild2Manager>();
                var child1NewManager = child1Service.GetTradeManager<IChild2Manager>();
            }
        }


        public abstract class ParentService
        {
            public T GetTradeManager<T>() where T : IBaseManager
            {
                Type instanceType = null;
                GenericHelper.DependencyDictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T),out instanceType);
                if (instanceType == null)
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Type Not Implemented");
                if (!this.GetType().Name.Replace("Service", "").StartsWith(instanceType.Name.Replace("Manager", "")))
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Not Same Manager");
                return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(instanceType);
            }

        }
        public class Child1Service : ParentService { }
        public class Child2Service : ParentService { }

        public abstract class BaseManager : IBaseManager
        {

        }
        public interface IBaseManager
        {

        }

        public interface IChild1Manager : IBaseManager { }
        public class Child1Manager : BaseManager, IChild1Manager { }


        public interface IChild2Manager : IBaseManager { }
        public class Child2Manager : BaseManager, IChild2Manager { }


        public static class GenericHelper
        {
            public static Dictionary<Type, Type> DependencyDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Type, Type>() { { typeof(IChild1Manager), typeof(Child1Manager) }, { typeof(IChild2Manager), typeof(Child2Manager) } };
        }

    }
```

When you try to get manager of another type it will throw an error.